# use of ssh variable in the shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I want to use the variables of ssh in shell script.
suppose I have some variable a whose value I got inside the ssh and now I want to use that variable outside the ssh in the shell itself, how can I do this ?

```
ssh my_pc2 <<EOF
<.. do some operations ..>
a=$(ls -lrt | wc -l)
echo \$a
EOF
echo $a
```

In the above example first echo print 10 inside ssh prints 10 but second echo $a prints nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I would refine the last answer by defining some special syntax for passing the required settings back, e.g. "`#SET var=value`"

We could put the commands (that we want to run within the ssh session) in a `cmdFile` file like this:

```
a=`id`
b=`pwd`
echo "#SET a='$a'"
echo "#SET b='$b'"
```

And the main script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# SSH, run the remote commands, and filter anything they passed back to us
ssh user@host <cmdFile | grep "^#SET " | sed 's/#SET //' >vars.$$

# Source the variable settings that were passed back
. vars.$$
rm -f vars.$$

# Now we have the variables set
echo "a = $a"
echo "b = $b"
```

If you're doing this for lots of variables, you can add a function to cmdFile, to simplify/encapsulate your special syntax for passing data back:

```
passvar()
{
  var=$1
  val=$2
  val=${val:-${!var}}
  echo "#SET ${var}='${val}'"
}

a=`id`
passvar a
b=`pwd`
passvar b
```

You might need to play with quotes when the values include whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

A script like this could be used to store *all* the output from SSH into a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$(ssh user@host << _EOF
id
_EOF)

echo "VAR=$VAR"
```

it produces the output:

```
VAR=uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),10(wheel)
```

Comment: hmmm but if inside ssh there are about 1000 lines and 100 output variables but I want to use 10 particular variable of ssh, then  how can I use it..?

Comment: Either you can run a script on the remote side that only outputs what you're interested in, or if the data is too complex, you can gather the information in a large string, base64 encode it and output that, decoding and parsing it on the client side. You might want to try `fabric` (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) for complicated scenarios